# Resultado do select alimentando outros 2 selects

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho o select 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SD2.D2_DOC            AS NOTA,
CONCAT(RTRIM(SD2.D2_CLIENTE), ' - ', SA1.A1_NOME)        AS CLIENTE,
SD2.D2_COD              AS CODPRODUTO,
QEK_REVI                AS REVISÃO,
SD2.D2_LOTECTL          AS LOTE,
SB1.B1_DESC             AS DESCPRODUTO,
SB1.B1_X_ESPEC                                           AS NQUIMICO,
SC2.C2_XLOTEF         AS FORLOTE,
SC2.C2_XNPAIS         AS PAIS,
SC2.C2_XNOMFA         AS FABRICANTE,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SC2.C2_XDTFAB AS DATE),103)    AS FABRICAÇÃO,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(SC2.C2_XDTVALI AS DATE),103)   AS VALIDADE,
SB1.B1_XDCB           AS DCB,
SB1.B1_XDCI           AS DCI,
SB1.B1_XCAS           AS CAS,
QE6.QE6_XMANUS        AS MANUSEIO,
QE6.QE6_XDERRA        AS DERRAMAMENTO,
QE6.QE6_XTRATA        AS TRATAMENTO,
QEK.QEK_CERQUA        AS NLAUDO
FROM SD2020 AS SD2
INNER JOIN SA1020 AS SA1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SA1.A1_COD = SD2.D2_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN SB1020 AS SB1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SB1.B1_COD = SD2.D2_COD
INNER JOIN SC2020 AS SC2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SC2.C2_XLOTE = SD2.D2_LOTECTL
INNER JOIN QEK020 AS QEK WITH(NOLOCK) ON QEK.QEK_XORDEM = SC2.C2_NUM
INNER JOIN QE6020 AS QE6 WITH(NOLOCK) ON QE6.QE6_PRODUT = QEK.QEK_PRODUT
WHERE SD2.D2_DOC = '244788' AND SD2.D2_COD = '000878'
AND SA1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND SD2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND QEK.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND QE6.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
```

Que me traz o seguinte resultado:

```
CODPRODUTO  REVISÃO LOTE
000878          02  PS-010435/F01
```

preciso que com este primeiro select eu alimente os campos de outros 2 selects e no final se tornem um único resultado e possível?

2º select que precisa ser alimentado pelo  1º select.

```
SELECT
QE1.QE1_DESCPO    AS CARACTERISTICAS,
QE8.QE8_TEXTO     AS ESPECIFICAÇÕES,
QE8.QE8_METODO    AS METODO
FROM QE8020 AS QE8
INNER JOIN QE1010 AS QE1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON QE1.QE1_ENSAIO = QE8.QE8_ENSAIO 
WHERE QE8.QE8_PRODUT = '000878' AND QE8.QE8_REVI = '02' 
ORDER BY QE8_SEQLAB
```

3º select que também precisa ser alimentado pelo 1º select.

```
SELECT
QER_LOTE,
QER_REVI,
QEQ.QEQ_MEDICA   AS RESULTADO
FROM QER020 AS QER
INNER JOIN QEQ020 AS QEQ WITH(NOLOCK) ON QEQ.QEQ_CODMED = QER.QER_CHAVE
WHERE QER.QER_LOTE = 'PS-010435/F01'
```

Desde já agradeço

Comment: qual banco está usando ?

Comment: Uso sql server 2012

Comment: Você pode juntar todos os selects assim:     SELECT * FROM (
            /* 1 SELECT */
            SELECT * FROM TABELAS_DO_PRIMEIRO  ) A
        LEFT JOIN ( 
           /* 2 SELECT */ 
          SELECT * FROM TABELAS_DO_SEGUNDO   ) B
        ON A.... = B.....
        LEFT JOIN (
            /* 3 SELECT */
            SELECT * FROM TABELAS_DO_TERCEIRO ) C
     ON  A..... = C......

Comment: É só usar joins para juntar os selects. Você só precisa definir as cláusulas de join colocando as variáveis de cada select que deverão ser iguais.

Comment: Me desculpem, mas ainda não entendi, sou novato em banco de dados, e nunca fiz um select dentro dos joins, se puderem ser um pouco mais claros eu agradeço mesmo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim:

Você tem de garantir que os campos de ligação nos JOIN apareçam nas 
tabelas.

Que os campos COD_PRODUTO e REVISAO estejam selecionados no SELECT A e no SELECT B e que a coluna QER_LOTE esteja selecionada tanto no select A quanto no C

```
SELECT * FROM  (

SELECT DISTINCT
SD2.D2_DOC            AS NOTA,
CONCAT(RTRIM(SD2.D2_CLIENTE), ' - ', SA1.A1_NOME)        AS CLIENTE,
SD2.D2_COD              AS CODPRODUTO,
QEK_REVI                AS REVISÃO,
SD2.D2_LOTECTL          AS LOTE,
SB1.B1_DESC             AS DESCPRODUTO,
SB1.B1_X_ESPEC                                           AS NQUIMICO,
SC2.C2_XLOTEF         AS FORLOTE,
SC2.C2_XNPAIS         AS PAIS,
SC2.C2_XNOMFA         AS FABRICANTE,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SC2.C2_XDTFAB AS DATE),103)    AS FABRICAÇÃO,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(SC2.C2_XDTVALI AS DATE),103)   AS VALIDADE,
SB1.B1_XDCB           AS DCB,
SB1.B1_XDCI           AS DCI,
SB1.B1_XCAS           AS CAS,
QE6.QE6_XMANUS        AS MANUSEIO,
QE6.QE6_XDERRA        AS DERRAMAMENTO,
QE6.QE6_XTRATA        AS TRATAMENTO,
QEK.QEK_CERQUA        AS NLAUDO
FROM SD2020 AS SD2
INNER JOIN SA1020 AS SA1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SA1.A1_COD = SD2.D2_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN SB1020 AS SB1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SB1.B1_COD = SD2.D2_COD
INNER JOIN SC2020 AS SC2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SC2.C2_XLOTE = SD2.D2_LOTECTL
INNER JOIN QEK020 AS QEK WITH(NOLOCK) ON QEK.QEK_XORDEM = SC2.C2_NUM
INNER JOIN QE6020 AS QE6 WITH(NOLOCK) ON QE6.QE6_PRODUT = QEK.QEK_PRODUT
WHERE SD2.D2_DOC = '244788' AND SD2.D2_COD = '000878'
AND SA1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND SD2.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND QEK.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND QE6.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' ) A 

LEFT JOIN ( 

SELECT
QE1.QE1_DESCPO    AS CARACTERISTICAS,
QE8.QE8_TEXTO     AS ESPECIFICAÇÕES,
QE8.QE8_METODO    AS METODO
FROM QE8020 AS QE8
INNER JOIN QE1010 AS QE1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON QE1.QE1_ENSAIO = QE8.QE8_ENSAIO 
WHERE QE8.QE8_PRODUT = '000878' AND QE8.QE8_REVI = '02' 
ORDER BY QE8_SEQLAB ) B

ON A.COD_PRODUTO = B.COD_PRODUTO AND A.REVISAO = B.REVISAO 

LEFT JOIN ( 

SELECT
QER_LOTE,
QER_REVI,
QEQ.QEQ_MEDICA   AS RESULTADO
FROM QER020 AS QER
INNER JOIN QEQ020 AS QEQ WITH(NOLOCK) ON QEQ.QEQ_CODMED = QER.QER_CHAVE
WHERE QER.QER_LOTE = 'PS-010435/F01' ) C

ON A.QER_LOTE = C.A.QER_LOTE
```

Comment: Reginaldo não entendi esta ultima linha  ON A.QER_LOTE = C.A.QER_LOTE porque o A esta também junto com o C e isso mesmo porque quando coloco o código no sql ela não reconhece este A que esta junto com o C

Comment: Se a coluna QER_LOTE não existe no primeiro SELECT você precisa adiciona-la.

Comment: Vlw Reginaldo obrigado.